# Chinese characters from pandas dataframe to CSV with Streamlit

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, streamlit

I have a pandas data frame with Chinese characters. When converting it into CSV like this works properly:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

But, when I want to integrate that into the [Streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) app, I'm getting this (see image) when downloading the CSV. This is the Streamlit code:

```
import streamlit as st


file_to_download = df.to_csv(encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
st.download_button("Download",df,"file.csv")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitely set mime='text/csv' and change to utf-8 and give it to download_button in the following way:

```
st.download_button('Download', data=df.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf-8'),file_name='file.csv',mime='text/csv')
```

Comment: This is the first thing that I've tried. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the document about pandas to_csv(encoding), its use in the output file.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

[encoding parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txStb.png)

So if you want to encode for cache, use encode("utf_8_sig").

maybe like this:

```
file_to_download = df.to_csv().encode("utf_8_sig")
st.download_button("Download",file_to_download ,"file.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The link provided does not show `utf_8_sig` option. Please recheck citations and/or code.

Comment: The encode method is [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).
And `utf_8_sig` is added BOM to help excel correctly read Chinese characters.